# Azure Timer Functions remember when they missed a scheduled time?

Tags: azure-functions

If I have an Azure "Timer" Function that runs on "every exact minute" `"0 */1 * * * *"` .. but if my code takes -more- than a minute, then the 'next run' does fire ... but waits for the current run to complete and then runs asap.

It's like it remembers that it missed a run and when the current run completes, it checks 'missed runs' and runs them ASAP.

Is this a configurable setting or 'by design'?

PROOF:

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pure.Krome, this is by design if the function execution takes longer than the timer interval specified the next invocation executes after the first one is finished. This is behavior is due to the singleton mechanism used by TimerTrigger in the backend. You can go through the additional information as [documented here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger).